# How to comment code blocks in Python that contain backslashes in strings?

Tags: python-3.x, comments

A backslash in a Python string indicates the beginning of a control command, for e.g. `text\n` adds a new line after 'text'. If backslashes in strings shall not be interpreted as commands a `r` must precede the string. That is usually the case if the string contains a Windows directory, i.e. `folder=r'C:\u'`.
However, if I want to comment several lines by `"""` I get an error

```
"""
folder=r'C:\u'
"""
```

```
(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 13-14: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

If I comment line by line by `#` then there is no error, however this method is not comfortable for commenting a whole block:

```
#folder=r'C:\u'
```

How to comment a whole a block of code that contains strings with backslashes?

Python 3.10.9, IPython 8.7.0, Spyder 5.4.2, Windows 10

**Edit**

I am not looking for answers or comments in the sense "Don't use Windows, use Linux!"

Comment: Does your IDE not have a shortcut to comment out a block?

Comment: The shortcut comments out every line by `#`. But this seems not comfortable for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the `r` prefix to a triple-quoted docstring to make it a raw string literal:

```
r"""
folder=r'C:\u'
foo='bar'
"""
```

Excerpt from [PEP-257](https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/):

> Use `r"""raw triple double quotes"""` if you use any backslashes in your
> docstrings.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a `\` is gonna be formatted, like `\n` for new line the only way to prevent that is to use `\\`, with that python gonna understand you just want to use `\\` and no a format.

At the end you get that:

```py
"""
folder=r'C:\\u'
"""
```

Else you can write the path in the same as linux like that:

```py
"""
folder=r'C:/u'
"""
```

Which don't cause any trouble with format.

Comment: Usage of \\ or / is not the style you write directories in Windows. I would like to have my folders in the style `c:\testdir`.

Comment: There are no other way to do that, I one of the reason why Linux is prefer to coding than Windows.

Comment: Cannot follow your argument. The usage of \ as a separator in Windows folder structure and the usage as a command in Python strings is just a coincidence. One could devise another character that has the function of \ in Python. Also it is not clear why commenting with # works but not with """. Usage of Linux would just lead to other unwanted coincidences.

Answer (score 0):

Since your goal is to comment a block of code, the correct method is to precede each line with `#`.

When you do this, the parser ignores the rest of the line.  You won't need to add `r` and you don't need to worry about `\`.

This would be tedious as a manual process, but any decent editor will allow you to select a block and comment every line with a single keystroke.  (In Spyder, try `Ctrl-1`.  Other editors will typically use `Ctrl-/` or a variation.)  Usually, the same key will uncomment a selected block.

The triple-quote method is not really a multi-line comment, but a multi-line string, which the interpreter is parsing.  Using it as a comment is not really 'Pythonic'.  You might run into other problems if, for example, the code block you are trying to comment includes triple-quoted strings.